Matrix operations intuition
I am attempting to find two matrices, neither the zero matrix, such that their product and
sum are both the zero matrix.
I have tried several combinations where:
\begin{align*}
A = [1,-1;-1,1], B = [-1,1;1,-1], AB = 0, A+B = 0
\end{align*}

Try matrices that are mostly $0$.

Since $A=-B$, the product requirement becomes $-A^2=0$, which means you're looking for a nilpotent matrix of index 2

What's the question?

Have you tried
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \; B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}?
$$
Then $A+B=0$ and $A^2=AB=BA=B^2=0$.
